# Python - Loop 100 times over a specified time

Tags: python, loops, time

I'm looking at creating a randomizing script in Python to execute a loop over a specific amount of time. If I wanted to run a loop 100 times within 5 days at random times within that 5 days, what would be the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick a hundred uniformly distributed random points along the interval and sleep between them:

```
import random, time

DURATION = 5 * 86400  # five days
EXECS = 100

now = time.time()
points = sorted(random.random() * DURATION + now
                for i in xrange(EXECS))

for p in points:
   now = time.time()
   if p > now:
       time.sleep(p - now)
   # run your loop here
```

Comment: thanks for correct code ... I had the same idea ;-)

But in your headline you were probably talking about 100 points?

Comment: @zen you're right, corrected now. The pseudocode in your answer looks similar, but the important difference is that it busyloops between two runs, which is unacceptable for a program intended to run for days on end.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, therefore i added the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could "pre-plan" your randomized times to get the perfect fit in your time range. This assumes your loop time is insignificant in the scale of days (for 100 runs). You would need to add something if you wanted to be really exact

```
import random, time

def Rand_Run(func, time_range, num_runs):
    # time range passed as days / convert to seconds
    time_range = time_range*3600*24

    # create a list of random numbers and a scaling factor for your time period
    r_items = [random.random() for i in xrange(num_runs)]
    r_scale = time_range/sum(r_items)

    # create the list of time delays between runs
    r_time_delays = (r_item*r_scale for r_item in r_items)

    # run the function between random time delays
    for r_time_delay in r_time_delays:
        func()
        time.sleep(r_time_delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT Python, but some idea:

```
duration = 5*24*60*60 //duration in seconds
for i = 0 to 99
    array(i)=rand()*duration
end
sort array
counter=0
while time_elapsed<duration
    if (time_elapsed>=array(counter))
        DO SOMETHING
        counter=counter+1
    end
end
```

Comment: DO SOMETHING is the place, where you can call your "Loop"

Instead of an while-loop arround it, you also can send your device to sleep.

After the counter was increased:

SLEEP (array(counter)-time_elapsed)

or something else to tell the system how long to wait for the next run.